# JQuery UI: How to get the selected tab to change color without loading jqueryui.css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am new to jQuery, so I apologize for trivial questions.

I'm trying to write a simple tabbed web page.  Everything works except the selected tab does not change to the selected tab color/text.  I have a css that I use to control active/selected tabs.  It works for hovering (the tab changes to hover color).  But after the tab is clicked it goes back to the unselected color.

I am not using the default jqueryui.css because I'm trying to build and learn things on my own.  But here I'm stumped.  I've tried adding all sorts of variations of .ui-tabs-selected and .ui-state-active to my css, to no avail.

Using the code inspector in chrome, I see that jquery applies the styles ui-state-active and ui-tabs-selected.  But how do I specify them in css to be activated?

Thank you!

here are the code snippets:

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Patient Records Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabs2.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tables.css" media="screen">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabbed_box_1" class="tabbed_box">
   <div class="tabbed_area">
     <h4>My title</h4>
       <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
           <li><a href="#tab1" >A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tab2" >B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tab3" >C</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tab4" >D</a></li>
        </ul>
                <div id="tab1_content" class="content">
                   <p>This is the text for tab 1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2_content" class="content">
                    <p>This is the text for tab 2</p>
                </div>

                <div  id="tab3_content" class="content">
                     <p>This is the text for tab 3</p>
                </div>

                <div  id="tab4_content" class="content">
                    <p>This is the text for tab 4</p>
                </div>
        </div>
   </div>    <!- End of tabbed_area->
</div> <!– End of tabbed_box_1 –>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    background-color:#687f93;
    margin:40px;
}

#tabbed_box {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width:300px;
}

.tabbed_box h4 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:23px;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.tabbed_box h4 small {
    color:#e3e9ec;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:9px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
    left:6px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
}

.tabbed_area {
    border:1px solid #494e52;
    background-color:#748593;
    padding:8px;
}

ul.tabs {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
}
ul.tabs li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    background-color:#464c54;
    color:#ffebb5;
    padding:8px 14px 8px 14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:9px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border:1px solid #464c54;
    background-image:url(../images/tab_off.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:bottom;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background-position: -420px -31px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#2f343a;
    border-color:#2f343a;
}
ul.tabs li a.current, ul.tabs li a.current:hover, ul.tabs li.current a, .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active, .ui-state-active, .ui-tabs-selected {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#282e32;
    border:1px solid #464c54;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-image:url(../images/tab_on.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: -420px -62px;
}

.content {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #464c54;
    background-image:url(../images/content_bottom.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:bottom;
}      

ul.tabs {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}

.content ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.content ul li {
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d6dde0;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    font-size:13px;
}
.content ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#3e4346;
}
.content ul li a small {
    color:#8b959c;
    font-size:9px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    left:4px;
    top:0px;
}
.content ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}

.ui-tabs-hide { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to CSS

```
ul.tabs li.ui-state-active,ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-selected { your styling }
ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-active a, ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-selected a{ your styling }
```

In HTML change

```
id="tab1_content" to id="tab1"
id="tab2_content" to id="tab2"
id="tab3_content" to id="tab3"
id="tab4_content" to id="tab4"
```

In your CSS code all styling is applied to the `a` >> `ul.tabs li a` but `ui-state-active` and `ui-tabs-selected` styling you apply to the `li`, not `a`. It is the reason why you can't see it.

Comment: You are right, thank you so much.   PS - you meant "ul.tabs li.ui-state-active a" as the first entry in the second line.

Comment: So I have this setup and I added another tab to it.  I want the content div that corresponds to that tab to display a dashboard-styled page, with a 2x2 "table" of divs.  I'm trying to to use table to house the div elements, but so far haven't figured out how do that.  The dashboard divs all display in one column.  Any help, please?

Comment: @elana crate another question, you forgot to check mark this answer

Answer (score 3):

In my case (jquery 1.10.2) this is what worked:

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited { your code}
```